# How to rewrite HTTP get request with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite HTTP get request. It request looks like this

`example/index.php?opt=1&cat=1`

I used this rule on my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*) index.php?opt=$1&cat=$2
```

and it works fine.

So when I type `example/index/1/1` it goes on page `example/index.php?opt=1&cat=1`,
when I type `example/index/1/2` it goes on page `example/index.php?opt=1&cat=2`.

But when I click on `example/index/1/3` it does not go on `example/index.php?opt=1&cat=3`. How can I rewrite rule. Is it possible to rewrite multiple HTTP get request on same project, because I have and something like this `example/demo.php?par1=x&par2=y`

Comment: If the third "example"-example does not work that might be a caching problem, there is no reason why that url should be handled different. I suggest you make a deep reload / clear your browser cache.

Comment: Are you using some CMS/PHP framework?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment above, the issue with the third example url pointing to the index script is probably a caching issue. Try making a deep reload or clear your browser cache.

For a more general rewriting rule handling similar patterns:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example/([^/]+)/
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*) %1.php?opt=$1&cat=$2
```

Note however that the regular expression you use inside that RewriteRule is not robust: depending on the structure of your incoming requests you might experience unexpected behavior. I would suggest something like this instead, which assumes that you place that .htaccess style file in your DocumentRoot:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^example/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? $1.php?opt=$2&cat=$3 [QSA]
```

And last not least some general note: *if* you have control over the http servers configuration you should always prefer to place such rules inside the host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notorioously error prine, make things complex, are hard to debug and really slow the server down. They only make sense if you do *not* have control over the server configuration or if an application needs to make dynamic changes to the setup.